# How it is possible to wait inside thread loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, wait

i want to know how it is possible to wait for a work to done and then continue and create new one

```
while(!stop)
{
    CreateWork();
    waitForWorkToDone();
}
```

wait must not block calling thread
how i can achive this?

Comment: Try a condition variable.

Comment: "Wait" and "block" are nearly synonymous. How can a thread possibly wait without blocking?

Comment: 'wait for a work to done' and 'must not block calling thread' sound like they're mutually exclusive conditions.

Comment: i am looking a way
i have some works that must be done serially on one thread.i must wait for one to complete then start new one without starting new thread

Comment: Casey and I do not understand your requirement at all.  It makes no sense.

Comment: Remove the while loop. Build some notification mechanism for "work is done".

Comment: This is beginning to sound like an XY problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you can rely on the operating system providing a facility to block until notified with or without a timeout.  Thus, your thread correctly does not use unnecessary CPU cycles by performing a busy wait, but is still able to respond to program state changes.  With POSIX threads, you can use a *condition timed wait*.  I'll illustrate with the boost implementation, but the concept extends generally.

```
do
{
  boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(state_change_mutex);
  boost::system_time const timeout = boost::get_system_time() + boost::posix_time::seconds(5);

  state_change_cond.timed_wait(lock,timeout);

  ...

} while(!done);
```

Overall this thread will loop until the *done* sentinel value becomes true.  Other threads can signal this thread by calling

```
state_change_cond.notify_all();
```

Or in this example if no signal happens in 5 seconds then the thread wakes up by itself.

Note that *condition variables* require locking by *mutexes*.  This is to guarantee that the thread is awoken atomically and that it will behave correctly in a mutually exclusive section as inter-thread signaling implicitly is.

Answer (score 0):

How about Creating a Signal. Create a handler that creates `CreateWork()` and signals when the job is done! Just a Suggestion